# Set background image with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am using `<picture><source srcset>` for image responsive. A requirement is images inside `<picture>` has to be set as background images.

I used jQuery to take image URLs and set them as background images. I then remove srcset so that they are not images anymore but become background images.

Problem: Somehow the url value doesn't show in `'url(myBG)'` It shows `<source media="(min-width: 768px)" style="background-image: url("myBG");">` in inspector.  Please take a look at my JS and give me a hand.

Thanks

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cr5zsL1d/)

JS

```
$('source').each(function() {
    var myBG = $(this).attr('srcset');
  console.log(myBG);
$(this).css('background-image', 'url(myBG)');
$(this).removeAttr('srcset');
})
```

HTML

```
<div>
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
  <source media="(min-width: 414px)" srcset="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_white_flower.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_pink_flowers.jpg">
</picture>
</div>
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post for clarity, it is very hard to understand as-is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're passing `myBG` in as a string. It should look like this: `'url('+myBG+')'`

```js
$('source').each(function() {
  var myBG = $(this).attr('srcset');
  console.log(myBG);
  $(this).css('background-image', 'url('+myBG+')');
  $(this).removeAttr('srcset');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
  <source media="(min-width: 414px)" srcset="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_white_flower.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_pink_flowers.jpg">
  </picture>
</div>
```